# For the Menu Component of Material Design Web Components, how do I capture the "MDCMenu:selected" event in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, events, mdc-components

I am using the [Material Design Web Components component called "Menu."](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/tree/master/packages/mdc-menu)

After launching the menu, I need to be able to accessibly handle all the ways a "menu item" could be "selected." Adding an on-click via my framework's templating language (vue) works, however, adding methods for on-enter and other keys does not work. Example:

```
  <li
    v-for="option in options"
    :key="option"
    class="mdc-list-item"
    @click="onChange(option)" // this works
    @keyup.enter="onChange(option)" //this doesn't work
    role="menuitem">
```

I expect this is because the `enter` key has event handlers for closing the menu, which are catching my keypresses. I'm not entirely sure.

In any case, it seems the "proper" way to handle selections is via the `MDCMenu:selected` event. The description from the docs:

> [`MDCMenu:selected` is] Used to indicate when an element has been selected. This event also includes the item selected and the list index of that item.

However, there are no instructions on how to capture this event. I've tried:

```
this.menu = new MDCMenu(this.$refs.menu);
this.menu.root.addEventListener(
  'MDCSimpleMenu:selected', ()=>{console.log('HELLOOOOOO')});
```

Which caused lots of `undefined` errors, which is weird because I can access `this.menu.root` and it appears to be a DOM element.

I've also tried:

```
this.menu = new MDCMenu(this.$refs.menu);
this.menu.addEventListener(
  'MDCSimpleMenu:selected', ()=>{console.log('HELLOOOOOO')});
```

Which threw an error about how `addEventListener` is not a function existing on `this.menu`;

I've searched through the source code but didn't find anything obvious about event handling or emitting.

**How can I capture the `MDCMenu:selected` event?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The function is apparently called `listen`, and takes in the full string event name as the first argument, and the function to be invoked as the second argument.

```
 this.menu.listen('MDCMenu:selected',()=>{
   console.log('hi');
 });
```

This is not documented anywhere I could find, I guessed it. If anybody can find the documentation I will accept that answer instead.

Comment: Thanks for this solution. But it is really sad that they don't have any documentation :(